# Count of array showing it is full but not elements are inside

Tags: php, html, arrays

I currently have a php document with an entry box like below.

```
<label>Insert Data
<textarea rows="25" name="new_value"><?php echo $_POST['new_value']; ?></textarea>
</label>
```

I am trying to do a mysqli query with the array I get from the input. To process the data to be used, I use this code:

```
function test_input(&$data) {
    foreach($data as &$value){
        $value = trim($value);
        $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
    }
    return $data;
}

$new_value = explode("\r\n", $_POST['new_value']);
$new_input = test_input($new_value);

echo count($new_input);
echo $new_input;
```

What I get when it echo's the count is 7 (the number of entries I put in), but when it echo's the array, all I get is "Array" and then nothing else. Obviously from the count I have an array full of elements. I am confused as to why the array would show nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array` is a data type.

When you try to `echo` an array an implicit transformation from `array` data type to `string` data type is performed. Because only strings can be `echo`ed.

String representation of array is word `Array`.

If you want to see array contents - use `print_r` or `var_dump`, for example.