# php cannot send posted array elements

Tags: php

I successfully passed following values with AJAX post method to my PHP file

```
name:John
email:test@test.com
comments:Hello
category_list[]:Books
category_list[]:Documents
```

The problem is that the following code sends `HelloArray` instead of `HelloBooksDocuments`. Could you please help me to find my mistake.

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$name = $_POST["name"]);    
$comments = $_POST["comments"];
$categories = $_POST["category_list"];  //the problem is here
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298832/count-of-array-showing-it-is-full-but-not-elements-are-inside/34298869#34298869

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
$comments= $comments.$categories;
```

With:

```
$comments= $comments.implode("", $categories);
```

The reason is that that variable *$categories* is an array, and you need to convert it to a string.

This you can do with [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). If you want them separated by a comma, then pass that as the first argument, replacing the empty string *""* I have suggested above.

Of course, you can change this, and use another separator of your choice.

Comment: using his expected output, maybe change the delimiter to `""` ?